# Polar plot of a function with negative radii using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

The following python code should plot r(theta) = theta on the range [-pi/2, pi/2].

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

theta = numpy.linspace(-numpy.pi / 2, numpy.pi / 2, 64 + 1)
r = theta

plt.polar(theta, r)
plt.savefig('polar.png')
```

This produces the plot:

[image: polar plot]

However, I would expect it to produce:

[image: expected polar plot]

The negative values of r(theta) seem to be clipped. How do I make it so that matplotlib plots the negative values of r(theta)?

Comment: Looks like this issue never got closed. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2203

Comment: @Alexander Kleinhans that issue is about a different problem. The problem it discusses is the inability to have a grid for negative radius values, not the inability to plot negative radius values.

Comment: I'm not sure if this linked issue is actually related, but if so, it has been solved by now, I'd say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first plot seems correct. It just doesn't show the negative values. This can be overcome by explicitely setting the limits of the r axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

theta = numpy.linspace(-numpy.pi / 2, numpy.pi / 2, 64 + 1)
r = theta

plt.polar(theta, r)
plt.ylim(theta.min(),theta.max())
plt.yticks([-1, 0,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

This behaviour is based on the assumption that any quantity should be plottable on a polar graph, which might be beneficial for technical questions on relative quantities. E.g. one might ask about the deviation of a quantity in a periodic system from its mean value. In this case the convention used by matplotlib is ideally suited.

From a more mathematical (theoretical) perspective one might argue that negative radii are a point reflection on the origin. In order to replicate this behaviour, one needs to rotate the points of negative `r` values by π. The expected graph from the question can thus be reproduced by the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 64 + 1)
r = theta

plt.polar(theta+(r<0)*np.pi, np.abs(r))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It should look like the expected plot because a negative radius is the same as a positive radius in the opposite direction. Compare to wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r+%3D+theta+from+-pi+%2F+2+to+pi+%2F+2

Comment: This a good general workaround, but it's kind of hackey. I realize that there may not be one, and I would prefer if there were some setting to switch.