# matplotlib unexpected results polar plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot simple function r = 3*sin(2*theta) using matplotlib:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
theta = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.01)
r = 3.0*np.sin(2.0*theta)
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
plt.show()
```

This is the result I get (it is not correct):

[image: matplolib]

This is what I expect to see (wolfram alpha): [image: wolfram alpha]

Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: matplotlib polar apparently doesn't do negative `r` see comment link in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982290/polar-plot-of-a-function-with-negative-radii-using-matplotlib/42982631#42982631

Comment: @f5r5e5d you answered my question

Comment: @f5r5e5d  could you make this your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this patches the polar plot for neg r

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
theta = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.01)
r = 3.0*np.sin(2.0*theta)
theta = theta + (1 - np.sign(r))*np.pi/2 # add pi to points with negative r values
r = np.abs(r) # make all r values postive to fake out matplotlib
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
plt.show()
```