# Complete polar graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The example below shows that `matplotlib` fails to plot dots (theta, r) where r is negative (plot it yourself, you will find that the result is a two-petal flower rahter than a four-petal one). How do I plot a complete graph in polar coordinate system that includes negative r?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.01)
r = np.sin(2 * theta)

plt.polar(theta, r)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you can add pi to theta where r is negative, then set r = abs(r) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132792/matplotlib-unexpected-results-polar-plot/43132971#43132971