# Plotting rose curve in python with even petals

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graph, polar-coordinates

I was trying to plot a rose curve in python with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)

r = 3* np.sin(8 * theta)

plt.polar(theta, r, 'r')

plt.show()
```

Now this is the rose curve `$r = 3 \sin{8\theta}$`, where since `$8$` is even so the curve should have `$2.8 = 16$` petals. But the output gives me a rose with $8$ petals.

I'm not sure if python understands the mathematical definition of the rose curve or we modified our definition so that Python understands it.
How can I get the output I desire?

Comment: I am guessing there is a bad hidden joke in `plt.polar`. If you look at the graduations, they go from -3 to +3 instead of 0 to 3.

Comment: Related question: [Polar plot of a function with negative radii using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982290/polar-plot-of-a-function-with-negative-radii-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is similar to the problem encountered in this related question: [Polar plot of a function with negative radii using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982290/polar-plot-of-a-function-with-negative-radii-using-matplotlib)

The problem is that `matplotlib.pyplot.polar` does **not** plot a curve in polar coordinates the way a mathematician would expect it.

A mathematician would expect that a radius of 0 designates the origin, and a negative radius is reflected across the origin; in particular, the polar coordinates `(r, t)` and `(-r, t+pi)` should designate the same point.

You can force this behaviour by manually adding `pi` to `theta` when `r` is negative, and replace `r` with its absolute value.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)

r = 3* np.sin(8 * theta)

# plt.polar(theta, r, 'r')  # remove this line
plt.polar(theta+(r<0)*np.pi, np.abs(r), 'r')

plt.show()
```

[image: 16-petals rose curve]